# Razor pages, как поменять надпись на кнопке?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor

Есть такой код на вьюшке

```
<form asp-action="AddFile" asp-controller="Home" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" value="Текст для кнопки выбора файлов"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Текст для кнопки отправки на сервер" />
</form>
```

Почему для `input type = "submit"` текст из value становится текстом на кнопке, а из `input type = "file"` просто игнорируется, и как мне поменять текст на кнопке выбора файлов?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1944267/5045688

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В предложенном комментарии указана ссылка на похожий вопрос - stackoverflow.com/q/1944267/5045688

Однако там все для HTML, и неоднозначно ничего - как применять это к ASP.NET

В общем, надпись "Выбрать файл" делаем не мы, а браузер и в разных браузерах она различается. Поэтому используются разные ухищрения и "грязные хаки", для такой, казалось бы, тривиальной процедуры - поменять текст на кнопке, а по факту - скрыть кнопку, заменить кнопку картинкой и закинуть туда текст, как то так оно работает внутри.

Нужно делать так

1. Качаем [Bootstrap.FileStyle](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/) и распаковываем в папку с проектом.
2. Во вьюшке, которая у нас отображается - добавляем следующий код, 5 строчек

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    //Непосредственно этот код - отвечает за саму кнопку. Все остальное выше и ниже - подключаемые библиотеки, нужные для такого, чтобы это работало.
     <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-text="Мой текст на кнопку выбора файлов" name="uploadedFile"/>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"></script>
```

Если не работает - открываем консоль браузера (F12 на хроме), и смотрим ошибки, возможно
он не находит вот этого вот

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"></script>
```

И это означает что адрес указан неверно, нужно понять - где у вас лежит эта библиотека относительно создаваемой странички и прописать адрес правильно.